# Working with accurate currency values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, floating-point, int, financial

I'm working on a system that uses financial data. I'm getting subtle rounding errors due to the use of floating point numbers. I'm wondering if there's a better way to deal with this.

One of the issues is that I'm working with a mixture of different currencies, which might have up to 12 decimals, and large numbers for other currencies.

This means that the smallest number I need to represent is `0.000000000001` * (1*10^-12) and the largest `100,000,000,000` (1*10^11).

Are there any recommended ways to work with numbers of this size and not lose precision?

Comment: what about [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)?

Comment: The problem is that I'm having rounding issues, I'm not really having issues with converting numbers to strings.

Comment: sorry, that's how js floating point is stored.

Comment: I'm aware. Hence my question.

Comment: I can understand.

Comment: Outside of [Decimal.js](https://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/) you might be better off creating a microservice written in another lang that makes use of [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) for the math. JS is not at all suited for this use case.

Comment: Thanks, @Chase. Both of those are good suggestions. If you turn it into an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really trying to stay in the JS realm you might consider [Decimal.js](https://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/) which should cover your precision range.
If I were writing this and needed to make sure there were no rounding errors I would likely try and use a [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) extension for another lang inside a microservice which was only tasked with the financial math. [GMPY2](https://gmpy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html) for Python3 is probably a good bet for something quick and easy.